# Running a Python Script from Electron

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I am trying to run python script first on load of electron app but getting few errors and stuck here

Getting some key error and developer tools is not loading showing blank white page in application

```
    let options = {
        mode: 'text',
        pythonPath: 'python',
        pythonOptions: ['-u'],
        scriptPath: './back_end_python/connector/',
    };
    
    PythonShell.run('test.py', options, function(err, results) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log('results: %j', results);
    });
```

Error

```
(node:16328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16)
(node:16328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:16328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PythonShellError: KeyError: 'formatters'
    at PythonShell.parseError (G:\application\front_end\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:261:21)
    at terminateIfNeeded (G:\application\front_end\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:144:32)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (G:\application\front_end\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:136:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "back_end_python\connector\test.py", line 277, in <module>
      logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py", line 71, in fileConfig
      formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\config.py", line 104, in _create_formatters
      flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\configparser.py", line 958, in __getitem__
      raise KeyError(key) {
  traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n' +
    '  File "back_end_python\\connector\\test.py", line 277, in <module>\r\n' +
    "    logging.config.fileConfig('../logging.ini', disable_existing_loggers=False)\r\n" +
    '  File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\logging\\config.py", line 71, in fileConfig\r\n' +
    '    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)\r\n' +
    '  File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\logging\\config.py", line 104, in _create_formatters\r\n' +
    '    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]\r\n' +
    '  File "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\configparser.py", line 958, in __getitem__\r\n' +
    '    raise KeyError(key)\r\n' +
    "KeyError: 'formatters'\r\n",
  executable: 'python',
  options: [ '-u' ],
  script: 'back_end_python\\connector\\test.py',
  args: null,
  exitCode: 1
}
results: null
```